# Location of automounted USB devices

Tags: usb, python, automounting, openbox

I am creating a GUI app using tkinter and python. The app calls for a user to plug in a usb flash drive containing video files. I am launching the app with openbox. The USB does not seem to be automatically mounted or is at a different location than when launching the app with LXDE (`/media/pi`). Where is the USB device mounted (path) or if it isn't how do I configure the pi to mount it automatically when using openbox?

This is the code I'm using to access the USB now assuming that it is already mounted.

```
for root, dirs, self.files in os.walk('/media/pi'):
```

Comment: You can use udev.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few different ways to automount storage devices on linux. Even the location of the mounts varies quite bit. Also not all system are set up to automount devices and some desktop environments will automount when you access them others when you plug them in.

Basically, to make it portable you cannot rely mount points in a location to find devices.

Instead you should find the devices, filter the removable ones/ones you are interested in and then map them to where they are mounted (if at all mounted). Using python you can get a list of removable devices with `pyudev` and then map them to mount points with `psutil`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pyudev
import psutil

context = pyudev.Context()

removable = [device for device in context.list_devices(subsystem='block', DEVTYPE='disk') if device.attributes.asstring('removable') == "1"]
for device in removable:
    partitions = [device.device_node for device in context.list_devices(subsystem='block', DEVTYPE='partition', parent=device)]
    print("All removable partitions: {}".format(", ".join(partitions)))
    print("Mounted removable partitions:")
    for p in psutil.disk_partitions():
        if p.device in partitions:
            print("  {}: {}".format(p.device, p.mountpoint))
```

Which will produce:

```
% python2 partitions.py
All removable partitions: /dev/sdb1, /dev/sdb2
Mounted removable partitions:
  /dev/sdb2: /run/media/mdaffin/ARCHISO_EFI
```

You can take this future by auto mounting partitions that are not mounted with `udisks` if you want.

Comment: Does pyudev and psutil come with Rasbian? I am getting an error saying it cannot be found.

Comment: The packages might be prefixed with `python-` (`python-pyudev` and `python-psutil`) but they might vary from this. Try searching for them with `apt-cache search psutil`.

If you cannot find them with the packagemanager then you can try using `pip` or `easyinstall` to install them. See [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/python.md) for more info on installing python modules.

Answer (score 0):

if device.attributes.asstring('removable') == "1"  is causing an error. is causing a 'bool' object has no attribute error. Is there any other way I can write this?